# Can't forward internet via to wlan via eth | iptables restore command not working

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, iptables, nat

I have a NanoPi M1 Plus device with Ubuntu OS in it which I am using it as a router. The device is getting the internet via ethernet cable (eth0 interface) and the WiFi AP is provided via interface wlan0.

I have written the iptables rules, but it doesn't seem to work. And IP_FORWARDING has been enabled.

Also, on executing `iptables-restore > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat` command it just freezes and no output is printed on the terminal.

**iptables.ipv4.nat**

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [186:14306]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [131:13477]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [142:11472]
:INPUT ACCEPT [27:2092]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [28:2049]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: "I have written the iptables rules" – do you mean you've only added them to the ruleset in /etc, or do you mean you've also loaded them via iptables into the kernel? The former won't take any effect until loaded.

Comment: I have loaded them in to the kernel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also, on executing `iptables-restore > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat` command it just freezes and no output is printed on the terminal.

It is waiting for *input*. The purpose of iptables-restore is to read the ruleset from a file, but you used the wrong redirection operator and told the shell to *write to* that file. The correct operator with this command is `<`.

Note that using `>` has immediately emptied the file's previous contents, so make sure to re-fill it with rules before trying again.

Other than that, the ruleset does not have any obvious problems. You might be having issues elsewhere, especially with the uRPF filtering feature which would refuse to accept packets from the "wrong" interface. Make sure to disable it via sysctl, by setting `net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter` to 0 for 'off' (or 2 for 'loose').

Comment: Yes, I was using the wrong operator. Though it didn't work for eth0 to wlan0 forwarding even after disabling `net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter`. But if I use an external wifi interface wlan1 as the station and make changes in iptables i.e.using `wlan1` instead of `eth0` .. iptables forwarding works perfectly